# ¿es conveniente todas las pulsasiones de teclas de mi juego en un mismo bucle?

Tags: c

Soy nuevo por aquí, y esta es mi primera pregunta.

La cuestión es que estoy haciendo un jueguito, usando SFML en C.
Lo elegí porque me resultaba más fácil que hacerlo en c++, y aquí estoy.
Por ahora me están saliendo todas las cosas que quiero hacer, pero mi pregunta va más relacionada con la simplificación del código que estoy escribiendo.
Para resumir el asunto, yo creé varios archivos, con las diferentes partes de mi juego, como el campo, el personaje principal, y un veículo, que es lo que tengo por ahora.

Y aquí va mi consulta.

Las líneas de las pulsasiones de teclas, las debería poner todas juntas en un mismo bucle como el del main por ejemplo, si están relacionadas?

y aquí les muestro algo de lo que hice:
Esto es lo que no estoy seguro si hacer o no.
Este es el bucle del main

```
while (!salir)
{
if (sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyA)) pasosConejo();

if (sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyF)) puerta_auto = true;
if (puerta_auto == true) puertaAbiertaAuto();

}
```

y lo que yo estaba haciendo, era meter las diferentes pulsasiones en diferentes bucles entrando y saliendo con variables bool así:

```
bool encendido = false;
bool motor = false;

while(encendido == false)
{

if (sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyW)) arranqueAutomobil();

}
//en el procedimiento arranqueAutomobil se cambia encendido a true, y motor a true.
while (motor == true)
{
if (sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyW)) {
aceleradorAutomobil(); }
else {
desaceleracionAutomobil(); }

if (sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyS)) frenoAutomobil();

}
```

Quizás es un lío lo que estoy haciendo, por eso estaba pensando en poner esas líneas en un solo bucle, y controlar cual se ejecuta con variables bool.

Y disculpen si estoy cometiendo muchos errores, soy tan solo un novato en este mundo.

Muchas gracias,
Un saludo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses c++ para aprender a crear juegos, tiene muchisimas ventajas c++ respecto c. Para mi una de las fundamentales es el uso del paradigma de POO para crear metodos muy eficientes y corto. C es un lenguaje de más bajo nivel que c++, por tanto te recomiendo que si buscas simplificar código para tu juego, es que aprendas Programación orientada a objetos en c++. Respecto a tu juego, te recomiendo que pases todo el código completo para poder ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: es que la poo nunca termino de entenderla, aunque intento siempre me trabo... no conoces un video o una página que lo expliquen de forma fácil?

Comment: Hay muchísima cantidad de cursos en youtube como Udemy, alguno habra que te sirva. Busca curso poo c++ y te saldrá. También te recomiendo que mires pdf de esto. Que te recomiendo que sepas usar en poo? Pues que sepas usar getters y setters, uso de constructor, sobrecarga de constructores y operadores(este ultimo me parece fundamental) y herencia(para mi es lo que debes usar si o si, para poder reutilizar código y usar metodos de otras clases). Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: genial, ya estuve encontrando algo interesante. muchas gracias por responder. un saludo.